# bootstrap dropdown-menu doesn't display on craftpip jquery confirm

Tags: jquery, confirm

Need your help again (previous question was nat a frank success, still not answered currently, but i'll be back on it soon).
This one is pretty clear, and though i can't find the answer.

I've made a simple page, with a dropdown menu (working), and a dropdown menu in a jquery confirm modal, not working (hence my presence here) : 
http://olif.ddns.net/Nouveau1.html

In the modal, the ul seems to be displayed (at least, that's what tells me chrome inspector), but still i can't see it.
On the main page, works like a charm ...

Worse again, on FF and IE, it doesn't display at all ...

I've been searching for a few hours, leading me crazy.

Any help really appreciated !

Oliv.

Answer (score 0):

OKay, it was just about asking, i finally figured it out myself.
Jquery confirm content div has a css "Clip" property, and that's the issue.
Removing it (instead of better option, at least for the moment) solved my problem.
I'll look for a better option if i can find one, currently i just commented the part which adds the css clip property in jquery.js ...